# How to add items to a ruby array and then get its length?

Tags: ruby, arrays

As the question says, I'm trying to add elements to an array and get the length of the array once this element has been added. When I do this:

```
def array_plus_one(a)
  a << ''
  return a.length
end

p array_plus_one([1,2,3,4])
=> 5
```

So everything seems to be working right?, except that it isn't, cause for some reason the code isn't passing the RSpecs. I still get a

```
NoMethodError
undefined method `array_quantity_plus_one' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_3:0x007fa237395f90>
```

I cannot post the code for Specs itself, but it's expecting that if I originally type a 2 lengthed-array, by the time I *return* it, it will have 3 items instead of 2.

I think the problem is that I'm passing an empty object instead of an array item itself?, but I don't know how to do the latter. I have looked both online and here, but haven't being able to find the correct answer.

As Humza pointed out below the problem was with a typo which I had overlooked numerous times. Moral of the story: read and re-read both the Specs, the instructions and the methods.

```
def array_quantity_plus_one 
  ## some code here..
end
```

Is the right answer.

Comment: `"array_plus_one"` == `"array_quantity_plus_one"` # => false

Comment: The longer form of the above comment: You have a typo. Your specs are calling `array_quantity_plus_one`, but your method is called `array_plus_one`

Comment: Thank you @Shepmaster, that was indeed the right answer. I updated my question

Answer (score 3):

You've got a typo in your code.

The method isn't `array_quantity_plus_one`.

It is `array_plus_one`.

Comment: Well I feel super super dumb. I've been racking my head for the last two days and I couldn't figure out what the problem was. Thanks for the help.